# Congruence Modulo a Sublattice

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, number-theory

Recently, I was reading [this](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/6E7EE9DAABF64BF4DF713B20C87F7C8F/S0008439500054813a.pdf/on_a_combinatorial_problem_in_number_theory.pdf) paper by Lindström about the combinatory detection problem. There's a paragraph in it that I don't understand. Let $M$ be a finite set of rational integers. Suppose for some set of $m$-dimensional column vectors $\{v_1, \dots, v_n\}$ with components in $M$, and some coefficients $\epsilon_1, \dots \epsilon_n \in \{1, \dots, k-1\}$ that the sum
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n \epsilon_i v_i$$
uniquely determines $\epsilon_1, \dots, \epsilon_n$. Then $\{v_1, \dots, v_n \}$ are called a detecting set.

I'm having difficulty understanding what Lindström means when he says

> Let $v_1, \dots, v_m$ be $m$-dimensional independent vectors with all components from M. They generate a sublattice $\Lambda$ in the lattice $\mathcal{K}$ of all $m$-dimensional vectors with integral components. Assume that $v_{m+1}, \dots, v_n$ have all components in $M$, and that the sums
> $$\sum_{i= m+1}^n \epsilon_i v_i$$

are **incongruent modulo $\Lambda$. Then, $\{v_1, \dots, v_n \}$ is a detecting set.**

I don't quite understand what it means for two vectors two be congruent with respect to a sublattice. At first, I guessed that a possible definition would be that given two vectors $v, v' \in \mathcal{K}$, $v$ is congruent to $v'$ if and only if there exists $q \in \Lambda$ and $k, k' \in R$ such that $k'v' = kv$. I'm pretty sure this guess is wrong. For one, if this is correct, then I see no reason why $\{ v_1, \dots, v_n \}$ should be a detecting set. Secondly, Lindström later says that

> By a lemma in geometric number theory, the number if residue-classes in $\mathcal{K}$ modulo $\Lambda$ is $\vert \det (v_1, \dots, v_n) \vert$.
> Which implies that the number residue-classes is finite, which wouldn't be the case with my definition.

I looked online to try to find a definition for congruence of vectors modulo a lattice. I wasn't able to find one. I assume I either don't understand what Lindström means by congruence modulo $\Lambda$ or I've got some other massive misconception. I'd greatly appreciate if someone could explain what it means for two vectors to be congruent modulo a lattice, (or point out some other error in my reasoning). Thanks in advance.

Comment: The usual definition is that $v$ is congruent to $w$ modulo the lattice $\Lambda$ if $v - w \in \Lambda$. That is, we consider $\Lambda$ as an additive subgroup of the vector space and construct the quotient group. This has the property you want; namely $| \mathbb{Z}^n /  \Lambda | = | \det ( v_1, \ldots, v_n) |$, where the $v_i$ make up a basis for $\Lambda$.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=21IzHN9-CjE , the author also has good notes for lattices on his webpage: http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/sp14/cse206A-a/index.html